# Hiding/Return send button with a fade effect on click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I would like to make my button disappear for 2 secondes by fading out and then re-appear after 2 secondes by fading in.

Does anyone know how to make that with javascript and CSS?
I am not a good expert a JS.

Comment: I wouldn't really say that is an effective method for preventing spam

Comment: Remember that a fade out affects the CSS styling of the submit button and although it's "hidden", it doesn't really deactivate the form. If a spammer used an automated program to fill out the form and submit it, have the button styled to be hidden won't prevent this.

Comment: Okay. But I still want to do that fade button.

Comment: have you tried fadeOut(2000) and fadeIn(2000)? Not that it prevents spam though.

Comment: Okay user2091820, as long as you realize its limitation and realize it's not really a solution to spam, I added an answer below and put a JSFiddle in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want, but dont expect it t solve any spam problems:

```
<input type='submit' onclick='$(this).fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn()'/>
```

Comment: Thanks.
Actually, I'm not using this for a spam protection, I'm using this so users can stop clicking two times (because they think the message is not sending, using jQuery btw)

Comment: Then this answers is the one you want, using jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

This will fadeout the button slowly, then when it's done fading out, it will wait 2 seconds before fading it back in again. Please note that this NOT an effective method for preventing spam. Although the button is "hidden" for 2 seconds, it doesn't really deactivate the form. If a spammer used an automated program to fill out the form and submit it, have the button styled to be hidden won't prevent this. But as a proof, feel free to use the code below.

```
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit my form!"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submitBtn").fadeOut('slow',function(){
        setTimeout('$("#submitBtn").fadeIn("slow");',2000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle to see what is going on here to help see if this is what you want...: http://jsfiddle.net/9Rf8j/

Comment: I would make it: `$("#submitBtn").click( function(){ $(this).fadeOut [...]` so the button disappears when the user clicks on it. Else it will disappear while the page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

To do an onclick functionality and keep it all in javascript code:

```
<input id='button' value='Button Text'>
<script language='javascript'>
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow',function() {
      setTimeout('$(this).fadeIn("slow");',2000);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

edit: You should probably disable the button instead of a simple fadeIn/Out - at the company I work for we just change the text out for "Processing" and users cannot reclick the button period (it doesn't come back).